# Jenkins Change the ownership of job programatically using Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using one job to create another job. I am copying template and modifying the parameters as per user requirement

Blow is snippet of code

{code}

```
public String createJob(String thisTemplate, String jobName, HashMap NewValues) {
  def jenkins = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
  def template = jenkins.getItem(thisTemplate)
  def job = jenkins.copy(template, jobName)
  job.save()
 // Change the values as per the requirement
  def NewJobName = Hudson.instance.getJob(jobName)
  setValues(NewJobName, NewValues)
}
```

{code}

All is working absolutely fine, It is creating template based job on users needs and then modifying parameters of newly created job

Now the problem is

1) The owner of newly created job is the "System" and not the user who ran the 'createnewjob'.

How to make sure that the owner of the new job is the owner who requested for the same instead of system being the owner.

Please help me on the issue...